# Detect duplicate MP3 files with different bitrates and/or different ID3 tags?

Tags: python, file, mp3, duplicates, id3

How could I detect (preferably with Python) duplicate MP3 files that can be encoded with different bitrates (but they are the same song) and ID3 tags that can be incorrect?

I know I can do an [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) checksum of the files content but that won't work for different bitrates. And I don't know if ID3 tags have influence in generating the MD5 checksum. Should I re-encode MP3 files that have a different bitrate and then I can do the checksum? What do you recommend?

Comment: Easy to use Python library for doing exactly this: https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu

Answer (score 16):

The exact same question that people at the old AudioScrobbler and currently at [MusicBrainz](http://musicbrainz.org/) have worked on since long ago. For the time being, the Python project that can aid in your quest, is [Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/PicardDownload), which will tag audio files (not only MPEG 1 Layer 3 files) with a GUID (actually, several of them), and from then on, matching the tags is quite simple.

If you prefer to do it as a project of your own, [libofa](http://code.google.com/p/musicip-libofa/) might be of help.

Comment: Also Picard is open source and MusicBrainz can be used by your own code.

Comment: Interesting, how does it Picard generate this GUID?

Comment: @nemo: first, understand what MusicBrainz is: http://musicbrainz.org/doc/AboutMusicBrainz . Then read how it matches music content with the database records in http://musicbrainz.org/doc/HowPUIDsWork

Comment: @James: in case you haven't found an answer to the question you posed in your previous comment, please see my previous comment here.

Answer (score 4):

Like the others said, simple checksums won't detect duplicates with different bitrates or ID3 tags. What you need is an audio fingerprint algorithm. The Python Audioprocessing Suite has such an an algorithm, but I can't say anything about how reliable it is.

[http://rudd-o.com/new-projects/python-audioprocessing](https://web.archive.org/web/20111127160608/http://rudd-o.com:80/new-projects/python-audioprocessing)

Answer (score 3):

For tag issues, [Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/PicardTagger) may indeed be a very good bet. If, having identified two potentially duplicate files, what you want is to extract bitrate information from them, have a look at [mp3guessenc](http://shibatch.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think simple checksums will ever work:

1. ID3 tags will affect the md5
2. Different encoders will encode the same song different ways - so the checksums will be different
3. Different bit-rates will produce different checksums
4. Re-encoding an mp3 to a different bit-rate will probably sound terrible and will certainly be different to the original audio compressed in one step.

I think you'll have to compare ID3 tags, song length, and filenames.

Answer (score 2):

Re-encoding at the same bit rate won't work, in fact it may make things worse as transcoding (that is what re-encoding at different bitrates is called) is going to change the nature of the compression, you are recompressing an already compressed file is going to lead to a significantly different file.

This is a little out of my league but I would approach the problem by looking at the wave pattern of the MP3. Either by converting the MP3 to an uncompressd .wav or maybe by just running the analysis on the MP3 file itself. There should be a library out there for this. Just a word of warning, this is an expensive operation.

Another idea, use ReplayGain to scan the files. If they are the same song, they should be be tagged with the same gain. This will only work on the exact same song from the exact same album. I know of several cases were reissues are remastered at a higher volume, thus changing the replaygain.

EDIT:
You might want to check out http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/, which apparently can do spectrogram visualization. I imagine any library that can visual spectrogram can help you compare them.

This [link](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonInMusic) from the official python page may also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The Dejavu project is written in Python and does exactly what you are looking for.

https://github.com/worldveil/dejavu

It also supports many common formats (.wav, .mp3, etc) as well as finding the time offset of the clip in the original audio track.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for something similar and I found this:
http://www.lastfm.es/user/nova77LF/journal/2007/10/12/4kaf_fingerprint_(command_line)_client

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use length as my primary heuristic. That's what iTunes does when it's trying to identify a CD using the [Gracenote database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gracenote). [Measure the lengths in milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993971/mp3-length-in-milliseconds) rather than seconds. Remember, this is only a heuristic: you should definitely listen to any detected duplicates before deleting them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the successor for PUID and MusicBrainz, called **[AcoustiD](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/AcoustID)**:

> AcoustID is an open source project that aims to create a free database of audio fingerprints with mapping to the MusicBrainz metadata database and provide a web service for audio file identification using this database...
>
> ...fingerprints along with some metadata necessary to identify the songs to the AcoustID database...

You will find various client libraries and examples for the webservice at https://acoustid.org/

Answer (score 0):

First you need to decode them into PCM and ensure it has specific sample rate, which you can choose beforehand (e.g. 16KHz). You'll need to resample songs that have different sample rate. High sample rate is not required since you need a fuzzy comparison anyway, but too low sample rate will lose too much details.

You can use the following code for that:

```bash
ffmpeg -i audio1.mkv -c:a pcm_s24le output1.wav
ffmpeg -i audio2.mkv -c:a pcm_s24le output2.wav
```

And below there's a code to get a number from 0 to 100 for the similarity from two audio files using python, it works by generating fingerprints from audio files and comparing them based out of them using cross correlation

It requires [Chromaprint](https://acoustid.org/chromaprint) and [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/) installed, also it doesn't work for short audio files, if this is a problem, you can always reduce the speed of the audio like in this [guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video), be aware this is going to add a little noise.

```py
# correlation.py
import subprocess
import numpy
# seconds to sample audio file for
sample_time = 500# number of points to scan cross correlation over
span = 150# step size (in points) of cross correlation
step = 1# minimum number of points that must overlap in cross correlation
# exception is raised if this cannot be met
min_overlap = 20# report match when cross correlation has a peak exceeding threshold
threshold = 0.5
# calculate fingerprint
def calculate_fingerprints(filename):
    fpcalc_out = subprocess.getoutput('fpcalc -raw -length %i %s' % (sample_time, filename))
    fingerprint_index = fpcalc_out.find('FINGERPRINT=') + 12
    # convert fingerprint to list of integers
    fingerprints = list(map(int, fpcalc_out[fingerprint_index:].split(',')))      
    return fingerprints  
    # returns correlation between lists
def correlation(listx, listy):
    if len(listx) == 0 or len(listy) == 0:
        # Error checking in main program should prevent us from ever being
        # able to get here.     
        raise Exception('Empty lists cannot be correlated.')    
    if len(listx) > len(listy):     
        listx = listx[:len(listy)]  
    elif len(listx) < len(listy):       
        listy = listy[:len(listx)]      

    covariance = 0  
    for i in range(len(listx)):     
        covariance += 32 - bin(listx[i] ^ listy[i]).count("1")  
    covariance = covariance / float(len(listx))     
    return covariance/32  
    # return cross correlation, with listy offset from listx
def cross_correlation(listx, listy, offset):    
    if offset > 0:      
        listx = listx[offset:]      
        listy = listy[:len(listx)]  
    elif offset < 0:        
        offset = -offset        
        listy = listy[offset:]      
        listx = listx[:len(listy)]  
    if min(len(listx), len(listy)) < min_overlap:       
    # Error checking in main program should prevent us from ever being      
    # able to get here.     
        return   
    #raise Exception('Overlap too small: %i' % min(len(listx), len(listy))) 
    return correlation(listx, listy)  
    # cross correlate listx and listy with offsets from -span to span
def compare(listx, listy, span, step):  
    if span > min(len(listx), len(listy)):      
    # Error checking in main program should prevent us from ever being      
    # able to get here.     
        raise Exception('span >= sample size: %i >= %i\n' % (span, min(len(listx), len(listy))) + 'Reduce span, reduce crop or increase sample_time.')

    corr_xy = []    
    for offset in numpy.arange(-span, span + 1, step):      
        corr_xy.append(cross_correlation(listx, listy, offset)) 
    return corr_xy  
    # return index of maximum value in list
def max_index(listx):   
    max_index = 0   
    max_value = listx[0]    
    for i, value in enumerate(listx):       
        if value > max_value:           
            max_value = value           
            max_index = i   
    return max_index  

def get_max_corr(corr, source, target): 
    max_corr_index = max_index(corr)    
    max_corr_offset = -span + max_corr_index * step 
    print("max_corr_index = ", max_corr_index, "max_corr_offset = ", max_corr_offset)
    # report matches    
    if corr[max_corr_index] > threshold:        
        print(('%s and %s match with correlation of %.4f at offset %i' % (source, target, corr[max_corr_index], max_corr_offset))) 

def correlate(source, target):  
    fingerprint_source = calculate_fingerprints(source) 
    fingerprint_target = calculate_fingerprints(target)     
    corr = compare(fingerprint_source, fingerprint_target, span, step)  
    max_corr_offset = get_max_corr(corr, source, target)  

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    correlate(SOURCE_FILE, TARGET_FILE)
```

Code converted into python 3 from: https://shivama205.medium.com/audio-signals-comparison-23e431ed2207

Now you need to add a threshold for example 90% and if it passes the threshold, it assumes it's a duplicated