# How to pass in parameter in a sys.argv[] code -Python

Tags: python-3.x

i have tried to pass in my `dir` but i don't seem to understand system line argument..here is a sample code that checks for duplicate files in a dir, gotten from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748675/finding-duplicate-files-and-removing-them?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)...i don't know how to insert my own Path as parameter

```
def chunk_reader(fobj, chunk_size=1024):
    """Generator that reads a file in chunks of bytes"""
    while True:
        chunk = fobj.read(chunk_size)
        if not chunk:
            return
        yield chunk

def check_for_duplicates(paths, hash=hashlib.sha1):
    hashes = {}
    for path in paths:
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
            for filename in filenames:
                full_path = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                hashobj = hash()
                for chunk in chunk_reader(open(full_path, 'rb')):
                    hashobj.update(chunk)
                file_id = (hashobj.digest(), os.path.getsize(full_path))
                duplicate = hashes.get(file_id, None)
                if duplicate:
                    print("Duplicate found: %s and %s" % (full_path, duplicate))
                else:
                    hashes[file_id] = full_path

if sys.argv[1:]:
    check_for_duplicates(sys.argv[1:])
else:
    print("Please pass the paths to check as parameters to the script")
```

pls how do i pass in my `path`..?

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: the code is correct...i just don't understand the `sys.argv[1:]` part...how do i pass in my DirPath ?

Comment: Please note the *Minimal* in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Please remove anything that is not relevant to the question.

Comment: done it....can u help me,,,?

Comment: Are you asking us to explain this code or fix it?  Are you asking how to call it?

Comment: i get the code...its this part `if sys.argv[1:]:
    check_for_duplicates(sys.argv[1:])`..i don't understand...how can i insert my dirpath in the code

Comment: You pass the paths as arguments when you call the script `python myscript.py path1 path2`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Did it...thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sys.argv\[1\] meaning in script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117530/sys-argv1-meaning-in-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did the script method...
but i also got around with a better way by removing 
`if sys.argv[1:]:
    check_for_duplicates(sys.argv[1:])
else:
    print("Please pass the paths to check as parameters to the script")`

and replace it with a main function to execute the code
`if __name__ == '__main__':
    check_for_duplicates(yourPaths)`