# Access MP3 music data using Python

Tags: python, mp3

I'm trying to write a Python script for searching out duplicate mp3/4 files using the song's data as the base for comparison.  My situation involves many mp3/4 files with similar file names, but different ID3 tags.  At first I tried looping through and using md5 to find duplicate files (ignoring file names).  This, of course, didn't work when the ID3 tags didn't match.

As a result, I'm looking for a way to extract only the music data from an mp3/4 in order to run it through md5 and find any duplicates.  What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: The music will probably (while 'identical') come in different bitrates (unless you can be sure everything is lossless) which will make a *simple* `data` comparison useless. So you'll need a more advanced (probably statistical) technique. I'm sure someone on SO will be able to provide some pointers...

Comment: Good point, instead of simple md5 an fft frequuency analysis is more appropriate. However, the volume can be different. Then I suppose you would look for correlation between the two ffts and expect high correlation perhaps? It does get tricky because some songs can include "foresounds" - an intro, or a speech - that is hard to detect.

Comment: @Hamish: I wonder if he'd want to consider those as being different (e.g. a live performance of some song with, say, a spoken intro vs. a particular studio recording). It really depends on how you define "duplicate", I suppose. This is becoming quite an interesting problem. :)

Comment: Actually, a lot of the duplicates I'm trying to find exist because the mp3 files were drug into iTunes after they were already in the playlist, causing exact duplicates except for the ID3 tags.

Comment: @Faisal, good point, however, I would still throw those in the same directory or something like that. They are different versions of the same name. The, of course, there are also covers of an old song. Whether a simple fft can pick up on those is hard to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [id3-py](http://id3-py.sourceforge.net/) or [mutagen](http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/wiki/Tutorial) to strip out all the tags (both ID3v1 and ID3v2, they can both be on the same file), then computing the MD5 on the result.

Assuming iTunes didn't manipulate the file beyond tags they should be identical.  Transcoding obviously would make this approach invalid.

Comment: While quite disk intensive, stripping out the tags with Mutagen worked out pretty darn well.

Answer (score 1):

Use some fingerprint algorithm. You might know about [MusicBrainz](http://musicbrainz.org). They have listed [here](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/Fingerprinting) some fingerprint algorithms. They use AcoustId now which is probably the thing you should also use (it's good and it's free). There is the [Chromaprint](http://acoustid.org/chromaprint) library which can generate such a fingerprint.

I wrote a [Python module `ffmpeg`](https://github.com/albertz/music-player/blob/master/ffmpeg.c) which does the decoding via FFmpeg and provides a simple function to calculate the AcoustId fingerprint (using Chromaprint). [Here](https://github.com/albertz/music-player/blob/master/test_acoustid.py) is a small demo for that (which even queries MusicBrainz for the song).

It should be easy to build some tool using that to find all duplicates.

The fingerprint will be exactly the same if the audio data is exactly the same. It will be similar if the audio data is similar. See the [AcoustId homepage](http://acoustid.org/) for further information how you calculate the similarity if you don't just want to check for equality.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually pretty advanced, fuzzy logic-type stuff you're asking about.

This isn't an answer but take a look at the discussion in this article: [Detect duplicate MP3 files with different bitrates and/or different ID3 tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476227/detect-duplicate-mp3-files-with-different-bitrates-and-or-different-id3-tags) (It might qualify as a dupe actually... It's even Python-specific.)

Comment: Completely different problem.  These files are copies of the same MP3 with different ID3 tags, since iTunes tries to be smart and update the ID3 tags.  There should be no binary difference in the music, only the meta data.  Thanks for answering, though.  =-]