# python - Extract data from mp3 file

Tags: python, mp3

I am looking for a python library that is able to extract the actually data of a mp3 (the actual voices/sounds we listen to). I want to be able to use the data to compare with another mp3 file without the bitrate/encoding affecting the process. How do i go about it?

Comment: Okay. ... What was the question again?

Comment: Have a look at this,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250696/access-mp3-music-data-using-python[/link]

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476227/detect-duplicate-mp3-files-with-different-bitrates-and-or-different-id3-tags

Comment: @tijko That works if the mp3 files only differ by their ID3 tags. The files won't match if their bitrate are different. Is it possible to normalize the bitrate of both files?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Echo Nest Remix API](http://code.google.com/p/echo-nest-remix/). It's not a library, but it might be what you're looking for.  Alternatively, you could test out the [PyMedia python module](http://pymedia.org/tut/).

Answer (score 0):

Python has wave and the Wave_read object which has function named readframes(n). It will return series of hexadecimal characters (these are basically loudness/amplitude of sound wave at particular time). You can compare two mp3 series of hexadecimal characters but you need to take care of bit depth and number of channels, as the stream output is dependent upon them. Something like- One character for an 8-bit mono signal, two from 8-bit stereo etc.