# How to create an event listener for mp3 sounds

Tags: python, audio, record, voice

I have a mp3 file namd 'audio.mp3' but for some reason no matter how hard I try I cannot find a useful link to help me code a programm that will listen to the computer and when hearing a specific sound that is exactly like my file 'audio.mp3', do something (that ofc i'll code)

I kept searching online for modules i could use or help but I only came across links that tell me how to record sound :

```js
from playsound import playsound
playsound('audio.mp3')
```

I have no idea what to begin with :/
The perfect module I could think of is a module that I onlt have to give him the name of my mp3 file, then put an event listener and it'll do the part where it listens to my computer sounds and trigger my event when it hears my file

Comment: Does this help? [Detect duplicate MP3 files with different bitrates and/or different ID3 tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/476227/13552470)

Comment: @AnnZen Not really, the op there asks if there's a way to differentiate between two audio files differently encoded when I'm trying to detect audio from my computer and execute something when I hear an audio playing that looks just like my file

Comment: module playsound is for diferent use, he PLAYSOUND, not listen